# Type error on unpickle

Tags: python, pickle, typeerror

I have a dictionary that's pickled into a file "offsets.pickle". When I try to unpickle it with

```
import pickle
a = open('offsets.pickle')
b = pickle.load(a)
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/global/python-2.7.3-intel/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1378, in load
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "/usr/global/python-2.7.3-intel/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 858, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "/usr/global/python-2.7.3-intel/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1198, in load_setitem
    dict[key] = value
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

My code runs nightly and was running fine for a while, when suddenly this started to happen. Is it possible for me to recover what is stored in the file?

Comment: It appears that something in your *code* changed (probably a class definition).

Comment: What's stored in the pickle file is just a dictionary with strings pointing to integers. Shouldn't I be able to load this from the command line without an issue?

There are no classes in my code.

Comment: It appears your pickle has been corrupted indeed, not a class change. It is a `SETITEM` bytecode in the pickle stream setting a key and value on the `dict` expected to be on the stack. But there is a string object there instead.

Comment: Not sure how you can recover from that; the pickle stream is no longer trying to construct something sane.

Comment: Any ideas as to what could have corrupted the pickle stream? The file already has several days worth of data in it. If I have to start again, so be it, but I'd rather this not happen again.

Comment: Any number of things can corrupt data; it is impossible to tell what happened here, certainly not without seeing the file.

Comment: That said, I build huge systems on top of the ZODB, which stores nothing but pickles and it is *extremely* reliable. Corruption usually happens on the file-system level, not in Python itself. You can of course corrupt a pickle file from Python too (mishandling seeks and truncate and append).

Comment: Perhaps you should be using a database? Even something as simple as [sqlite](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) which comes bundled with Python 2.5+ would be more reliable than what you are doing.